# Identifying file format of web map layer?

Tags: web-mapping, file-formats

I am interested in extracting data from the map layer available [here](http://watchthemed.net/index.php/json/layer/9).

The data looks like this (I inserted linebreaks for readability):

```
Malta_SAR normal #LineStyle000 highlight #LineStyle001 SAR Zones Lybia (NO 
INFO IN IMO REPORT) 1 normal #LineStyle000 highlight #LineStyle001 SAR Zones 
Lybia (NO INFO IN IMO REPORT) 1 0 #LineStyle00 1 11.526082,33.171136,0 
11.531247,33.196851,0 11.537371,33.213983,0 11.566443,33.298784,0 
11.585108,33.364755,0 12,33.916667,0 12.218734,34.175,0 
12.40997642454452,34.37477266876127,0 23.583333,34.333333,0 24.1667,34,0 
25.150691,31.669654,0 SAR Zones Lines normal #LineStyle000 highlight 
...
```

Can anyone identify what file format this is, so that I can figure out how to read it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the first few lines at your link it looks like it is KML 2.2:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
-<Document id="Malta_SAR">
<name>Malta_SAR</name>`